# PHP constructor and a bounce of fields dependant on each other

Tags: php, design-patterns, object, constructor

`MyClass` has a bounce of fields, where each value depends on another instance value and, at the end, on a `DependencyClass`. A very simple example:

## Solution A (use constructor)

```
public class MyClass
{
    private $myField1, $myField2;

    public function MyClass(DependencyClass $dependency)
    {
        $value = $dependency->getValue();
        $value++; // Computations on dependency value

        $this->myField1 = $value + 3;
        $this->myField2 = $value - 1;
    }

    public function getMyField1()
    {
        return $this->myField1;
    }

    public function getMyField2()
    {
        return $this->myField2;
    }
}
```

My question is, is class constructor the right place where i should put this computation logic? Or would be more appropropriate to do some code duplication like:

## Solution B (constructor only for dependency)

```
public class MyClass
{
    private $dependency;

    public function MyClass(DependencyClass $dependency)
    {
        $this->dependency= $dependency
    }

    public function getMyField1()
    {
        $value = $this->dependecy->getValue();
        $value++; // Computations on dependency value

        return $value + 3;
    }

    public function getMyField2()
    {
        $value = $this->dependecy->getValue();
        $value++; // Computations on dependency value

        return $value - 1;
    }
}
```

or make `MyClass` merely a container and user an external assembler class like:

## Solution C (external assembler)

```
Class Assembler
{
    public getMyClass()
    {
        $dependency = new Dependency();
        $value      = $dependency->getValue();
        $value++; // Computations on dependency value

        $myClass = new MyClass();
        $myClass->setMyField1($value + 3);
        $myClass->setMyField2($value - 1);

        return $myClass;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd say it depends a bit, however Solution B looks most straight forward to me and that's often good when your code grows. Also I think you have simplified the example much, and it might have lost the problem while you did so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "it depends".  What are you trying to accomplish?

With Solution A and B, you've made the coupling to Dependency and the calculations an intrinsic part of the MyClass object: MyClass does not exist with Dependency, and it always uses Dependency a certain way.  Solution C, on the other hand, decouples MyClass from Dependency entirely, making MyClass a humble data object.

So the question is which one makes sense in whatever more concrete case faces you at a given moment.  Do you want the data in MyClass to be able to be constructed in a variety of ways in the future, or do you want it to always be created from Dependency?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your circumstance and needs.

If your computations are simple and always used, I'd put them in the ctor. (Solution A)

If one of the computations is complex and/or not always used, I'd opt for a "lazy evaluation" in the accessor and have the accessor cache the result once it is computed. (Solution B, but I would add caching of the result).

I recommend against Solution C.  It is really just the constructor in a different scope and thus your class is less cohesive.  It hides the dependency on another class.  It makes it difficult to test because the other class cannot be mocked or stubbed.  There is little reason for the class to exist--it is nearly the same as a read only array.